# How can I make a `overflow-x: hidden;` container show it's overflowed Y axis children?

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example:

I have a container and a box element, the child element is overflowed both XY axis:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Now, if I add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the container, the child gets cut on both axes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I make my child only showed on Y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clip-path` instead of overflow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  clip-path:inset(0 0 -200vmax 0); /* works like margin [top right bottom left] */
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```